# CSS. Can't center class and it's ':before' element

Tags: html, css, user-interface, web

I'm learning the :before and :after pseudo-elements but I don't understand why it's not centering.

**what I have:**
[image]

my code :

```
jsfiddle down here
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ecfobu3g/

If I remove **display: inline-block;** the :before element would transition from the left of the page, But I want it from the left of the .title main element.

In short I want to achieve the same effect of transition but I want the text to be centered horizontally.

I want the .title class to be centered horizontally and the .title:before also to be centered horizontally.

Comment: I need a little more info.  What exactly do you want centered?  Horizontal or vertical centering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a div around and text-align: center;

[Like this](https://jsfiddle.net/ecfobu3g/4/)

```
<div style="text-align : center; ">
  <h1 data-title='TiPS' class='title'>TiPS</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not working... It's the same as if I'd remove the **display:inline-block**

Comment: No it isn't ... Did you check the JSFiddle I've provide ? With that way, you keep the animation the same instead of removing display: inline-block which change the animation

Comment: Oh my bad. It works, I just forgot to uncomment the **display:inline-block**..
Thanks. One last question. why did you put **width:100%**?

Comment: No problem, you're welcome ! 
it's because I went too fast. It is not required to make it works because a div element is a block element so it already occupy 100% of the document size.

Answer (score 0):

You can add

```
width: 100%;
```

to your h1 element.  I'm not entirely sure if that's what you wanted.

Comment: It would be better to remove `display: inline-block`, which produces a shrink-to-fit width.